# Отправка массива посредством AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, запрос

Отправляю запрос на сервер следующим образом

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/words",
    data:{
        ...,
        'translations':$('#select-translation').val()
    },
    ...
});
```

поле `translations` является массивом(по крайней мере сервер ожидает массив). `$('#select-translation').val()` возвращает массив (`["1571", "1895"]`) но при отправке имя параметра меняется на `translations[]` и естественно не доходит. Собственно говоря вопрос: как правильно отправить массив?

Comment: `'translations':$('#select-translation').val().join(",")`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо огромное, оформите как ответ, я отмечу как верный!

Comment: Рад помочь земляку-криворожанину.

Comment: @Igor ну ничего себе!))) Мир - тесен а stackoverflow и по давно))

Comment: Мои бабы-деды жили на Сиволапа и Розы Люксембург. Кажется, обе улицы сейчас переименованы.

Comment: @Igor Да переименованы( я, честно говоря, и не знаю новых названий вообще. А сам где жил\живешь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
'translations':$('#select-translation').val().join(",")
```

с учетом того, что у Вас находится на серверной стороне.

Answer (score 0):

есть еще вариант отправлять данные так:

```
dataType: 'json',
data:{
    ...,
    /*без ковычек, ибо это объект*/translations:$('#select-translation').val()
},
```

вот мой рабочий код на эту тему:

```
$("#add_result").html("Добавляем...");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/device/add",
    data: {
      name: "device", 
      nomer: "123456",
      imei: "123456789012345"
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
    /*******/
      $("#add_result").html(json.txt);
    },
    error: function(x, t, m) {     
    /*******/
      $("#add_result").html("<option color='red'>Невозможно добавить устройство</option>");                  
    }    
  })
```